# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER

Tags: python, django, sqlite, factory

I get this error when I run `django==1.4.2` tests with `factory_boy==1.2` in Ubuntu 13.04.
These tests run in Ubuntu 12.10.

So the changes between them are `python==2.7.3` and `python==2.7.4`.
Does it change `sqlite` version in any way?

Could this be cause by anything else?

Full stacktrace:
http://pastebin.com/iVKvBZ9M

Comment: It's more likely to be that your installation of Ubuntu 13.04 is 64-bit, but the 12.10 was only 32-bit.

Comment: @Aya , This is true.But how does 64bit and 32bit cause this error? Also I have the test working on 64bit 12.10.

Comment: As for why you get the error, it would depend on the test case. You'd have to include the source code for one of the failing test cases.

Comment: Could you open the files and add a `print attr, getattr(self, attr)` before `res[attr] = getattr(self, attr)` to `File "/home/vignesh/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/factory/containers.py", line 75, in __fill__` to see what attribute causes the trouble and its value.